# Faucet hose not retracting smoothly

Tags: faucet

We recently had our kitchen remodeled and after the installation, I noticed that the power for the garbage disposal was placed right below the faucet. This prevents the faucet hose from smoothly moving when using the detachable faucet head (I have a Delta Ashton, #19922Z-SSSD-DST). When I pull out the faucet head, I have to push the hose back into faucet, which is a mild pain. Before attempting to move the outlet, any suggestions on how I might get the hose to move more smoothly around it?

[image: Pic of under-sink, where hose rubs against outlet]

Comment: The problem with "moving the outlet" is that the wires will probably not be long enough to move the box and any wire splices must be... contained within a box.

Comment: @JPhi1618 True, I'll likely need to find a way to work around it.

Comment: Perhaps a sloped "shield" attached above the j-box and ending below it? A large piece of a gallon water jug should work as a smooth bearing surface for the hose to ride across and also prevent chafing.

Comment: The shield idea is the way to go.  You might consider (if you're  up for your own chapter in  the new "How-To" book from Randall Munroe :-) )  putting more weights on the hose to enhance it's desire to retract.

Comment: I concur that the shield idea is probably the least expensive solution. And on an unrelated matter, the way you have your dishwasher plumbed directly into your garbage disposal is incorrect and could lead to macerated food from the disposal getting injected backwards into the dishwasher drain line.    The correct way is for it to go up to an airgap and then down to the disposal or at the minimum doing a high loop in the hose and then down to the disposal.  Of course I can’t see if there is a high loop there so I’m assuming there is not.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably shorten the sleeve through which the hose feeds so there's more clearance above the box. This alone would probably resolve the problem. The extra length doesn't appear to be necessary in this case. It's mostly to accommodate thicker mounting situations. Be sure to ease (bevel or smooth) the edge of the cut so it doesn't abrade the hose.

You could also try bending that sleeve, but brass tends to tear before it bends.

Answer (score 0):

Raise the weight. You'll get less line to pull out, but it'll retract. The line is binding on the electric box, but the weight is resting on the PVC pipe.

If the final position of the weight is horizontal it can't do its job.